# Two tables side by side in a function

Tags: php, html

I have this function to make a table with data from my DB.

```
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='2' style=\"margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px\">";

for($i = 0; $i<$aantalspelers; $i++){
    $querynaam = "SELECT voornaam FROM team WHERE id=$i" or die(mysql_error());
    $querytussenvoegsel = "SELECT tussenvoegsel FROM team WHERE id=$i" or die(mysql_error());
    $queryachternaam = "SELECT achternaam FROM team WHERE id=$i" or die(mysql_error());
    $querypositie = "SELECT positienaam FROM positie WHERE id=(SELECT positie FROM team WHERE id=$i)" or die(mysql_error());
    $naam = $db->query($querynaam);
    $naam = $naam->fetch();
    $naam_string = $naam['voornaam'];
    $tussenvoegsel = $db->query($querytussenvoegsel);
    $tussenvoegsel = $tussenvoegsel->fetch();
    $tussenvoegsel_string = $tussenvoegsel['tussenvoegsel'];
    $achternaam= $db->query($queryachternaam);
    $achternaam = $achternaam->fetch();
    $achternaam_string = $achternaam['achternaam'];
    $positie = $db->query($querypositie);
    $positie = $positie->fetch();
    $positie_string = $positie['positienaam'];

    $inserttable = "<th rowspan='3'><img src=\"images/spelers/$i.jpg\" width='85' height='130'/></th>"
        .'<tr><th>Voornaam</th><th>Tussenvoegsel</th><th>Achternaam</th><th>Positie</th></tr>'
        .'<tr><td>'.$naam_string.'</td><td>'.$tussenvoegsel_string.'</td><td>'.$achternaam_string.'</td><td>'.$positie_string.'</td></tr>';

    echo $inserttable;
}

echo "</table>";
```

Now this works fine and all, but i'd like to have like 2 rows in my table:

[id 0 info] | [id 1 info] 
[id 2 info] | [id 3 info]

but now my table is like:

[id 0 info]
[id 1 info]
[id 2 info]

how do I make it so it they are like 2 tables next to each other?

Thanks.

EDIT: to be more clear: I have it like this; [now](http://imgur.com/INVp4Ak,tspfyCd#0) but I want it like this; [want](http://imgur.com/INVp4Ak,tspfyCd#1)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want? When I run your code I get a table that is five columns by two rows per each iteration of your for loop which seems to be what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: i have it like this: [link](http://imgur.com/INVp4Ak,tspfyCd#0)
but i'd like it like this: [link](http://imgur.com/INVp4Ak,tspfyCd#1)

Comment: Can't you just make two tables and increment `$i` by `2` instead of `1`, or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: @Cezary Wojcik, I was just about to post that! Where are you getting the variables you are you using while building your string? Do they all contain the same value? Or is it going to be coming from an array? It's hard to build a solution to this when we are missing a bunch of code. You can do this a number of ways but we need more information.

Comment: let me just add some more code.. my mistake for not being clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index of the array combined with modulus to stack rows next to each other.

Something along these lines:

```
for($i = 0; $i<$aantalspelers; $i += 2){
        $table1_rows .="<tr><td>$aantalspelers[i]["id"]</td></tr>";
        $table2_rows .="<tr><td>$aantalspelers[i+1]["id"]</td></tr>";
}
```

Then just wrap the rows up in headers and footers and use css to float them next to each other:

```
$table_head = "<table><tr><th>whatever headings</th></tr>";
$table_foot = "</table>";
$table1 = $table_head.$table1_rows.$table_foot;
$table2 = $table_head.$table2_rows.$table_foot;
```

Comment: Incrementing by `2` is more efficient.

Comment: Check my recent edit, and yes I have tried this but is not the proper result.